# Pruning a specific dimension in a neural network using L1-norm

Tags: neural-networks

I've been playing around with pruning neural networks. One interesting thing I've found is that pruning the weights with the lowest L1-norm *along a specific dimension* seems to give better results than simply pruning all of the weights with the lowest L1-norm (which I believe is the standard method; for example this is what [torch.nn.utils.prune.l1_unstructured](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.prune.l1_unstructured.html#torch-nn-utils-prune-l1-unstructured) does).

Does anyone have an explanation for why this might be, or knows of any research in this area?

I'm aware that structured pruning removes entire channels in a specific dimension. But I'm referring to unstructured pruning here, where I remove a subset of the weights along a specific dimension.

Admittedly I've only done very limited benchmarking of this. See [this repo](https://github.com/nfergu/l1_dim_pruner) for my implementation, and some benchmark details.

Comment: Please, put more contents related to "the lowest L1-norm along a specific dimension". Especially, specific dimension. Also is there any other study in this method?

Comment: @CloudCho What I mean specifically is, pruning along dimension 1 (the second dimension) of each of the full-connected layers of the network. Specifically, I use torch.topk with dim=1 to find the values with the lowest L1-norm sorted along dimension 1. The implementation and benchmark results are here: https://github.com/nfergu/l1_dim_pruner/

Comment: Have you tried to perform pruning in other dimension?

Comment: @CloudCho Yes, I've tried pruning along dimension 0 (the first dimension). Performance is not as good (worse than standard L1-norm pruning).